# Line from middle of one div or td to the middle of another

Tags: css

For an online survey I want to show a scale:

[image]

The radio buttons and text are layed out using a table. How can I draw the line of the scale from the middle of the left text and radio button to the middle of the right text and radio button?

If possible, don't use graphics.

---

Relevant code:

```
.align_center {
    text-align: center;
    }

<table>
    <tr>
            <td></td>
        <td class="align_center">disagree</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="align_center">agree</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="align_center">1</td>
        <td class="align_center">2</td>
        <td class="align_center">3</td>
        <td class="align_center">4</td>
        <td class="align_center">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stackoverflow is great</td>
        <td class="align_center"><input name="so" value="1" type="radio"></td>
        <td class="align_center"><input name="so" value="2" type="radio"></td>
        <td class="align_center"><input name="so" value="3" type="radio"></td>
        <td class="align_center"><input name="so" value="4" type="radio"></td>
        <td class="align_center"><input name="so" value="5" type="radio"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your current markup and CSS

Comment: use divs instead of tables...

Comment: @Phlume As my question already asks: How do I draw a line from the middle of one div to another?

Comment: @codehorse "If possible, don't use graphics."

Comment: In theory, you could add a couple `div`s in the `td`s with your numbers, and apply some borders, but the solution would be convoluted and you would be adding a fair amount of non-semantic markup to your page. Do you have a good reason for not wanting to use a graphic?

Comment: @ChrisHardie Graphics never scale nicely (i.e. with sharp edges). But please post a solution with graphics, if you have one, just don't put text in the graphics.

Comment: Check out this http://jsfiddle.net/5LAUx/. Can you work with something similar?

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @kleinfreund Nice. I'll try that.

Comment: @t.niese All that Facebook supports.

Answer (score 0):

This is *one* approach, that feels a little complex but should be easily extensible. It does require a move away from `table`-based layout (which I regard as a plus, honestly), but instead uses a nested lists:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <ul class="header">
            <li class="header"></li>
            <li class="indicator"></li>
            <li class="indicator"></li>
            <li class="indicator"></li>
            <li class="indicator"></li>
            <li class="indicator"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li class="header">Stack Overflow is:</li>
            <li class="grade">
                <input type="radio" name="SO" />
            </li>
            <li class="grade">
                <input type="radio" name="SO" />
            </li>
            <li class="grade">
                <input type="radio" name="SO" />
            </li>
            <li class="grade">
                <input type="radio" name="SO" />
            </li>
            <li class="grade">
                <input type="radio" name="SO" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

With the following CSS:

```
ol, ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}

li {
    height: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1;
}

li.header {
    width: 10em;
}

/* just in case you set a default background-color for the headers */
li.header:empty {
    background-color: transparent;
}

li.indicator,
li.grade {
    width: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

li.indicator {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

li.header + li.indicator,
li.indicator:last-child {
    border-width: 0;
}

li.indicator::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 48%;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

li.header + li.indicator::before {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    right: 0;
}

li.indicator:last-child::before {
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    left: 0;
}

/* gives the scale numbers for the inputs */
ol ul {
    counter-reset: scale;
}

ol ul li.indicator::after {
    counter-increment: scale;
    content: counter(scale, decimal);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8wLgN/).